# ¿Cómo concatenar una URL en androidStudio?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un error no se concatenar 2 variables que quiero enviar en una URL por método GET las cuales son:

```
usuario="+usuario.getText().toString()
contrasena="+password.getText().toString().
```

Mi URL quedo así:

```
ConsultaPass("http://192.168.1.71/proyecto/consultarusuario.php? usuario="+usuario.getText().toString()+"contrasena="+password.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Parece que está bien, puedes decir si imprimes esa url si te sale la cadena que quieres? o donde ves que te falle?

Comment: tienes un espacio entre ? y usuario, eso no le va a sentar bien

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es tener un controlador en tu carpeta `proyecto` que te permita escribir la URL de esta forma:`http://192.168.1.71/proyecto/usuario/pedro` ... o sea, como un punto de entrada de una API. Es muy fácil de hacer y te permite construir URLs elegantes, modernas, profesionales en lugar del (para mi horrible) `http://192.168.1.71/proyecto/consultarusuario.php?usuario=pedro&apellido=perez&...&...&...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas en tu código:

- No estás separando los parámetros con `&`.
- No estás escapando correctamente los caracteres que montas en la consulta.

Puedes hacer uso de [`URLEncoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder) para codificar los caracteres especiales:

```
ConsultaPass(
  "http://192.168.1.71/proyecto/consultarusuario.php?usuario="
  + URLEncoder.encode(usuario.getText().toString(), "utf-8")
  + "&contrasena="
  + URLEncoder.encode(password.getText().toString(), "utf-8")
);
```

O, mejor aún, hacer uso de [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri) para montar correctamente la URI:

```
String url = Uri
  .parse("http://192.168.1.71/proyecto/consultarusuario.php")
  .buildUpon()
  .appendQueryParameter("usuario", usuario.getText().toString())
  .appendQueryParameter("contrasena", password.getText().toString())
  .build()
  .toString();
ConsultaPass(url);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! me ayudaste mucho es que no entendía bien como concatenar.

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda 